# Easiest way to iterate through a dataframe and get the product of the last 30 days

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe indexed with a DateTime column, and column A filled with float, what would be the most efficient way to create a column, B, that has as its values all of the individual products of all the values from that any particular row going back 30 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the rolling_apply function of pandas:

```
df['B'] = rolling_apply(df.A, 30, numpy.prod)
```

I assume your index is on a daily basis, otherwise, you need to modify the second parameter
which I set to `30`.

pandas features a lot of standard statistics for so-called rolling horizons, such as a rolling mean, or a rolling standard deviation. The product is not part of it as far as I can see, so you have to define it yourself in the above way. For further information, see the [pandas doc on computing individual statistics](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html).